# How to accept multiple types in Java annotation parameter?

Tags: java, annotations

I would like to use an annotation on a key string to configure the initial value for a property of that key.  E.g.,

```
@NodeProperty(initialValue = "bar") static final String "FOO";
```

Other code later processes the annotation, adding a key "FOO" with value "bar" to a particular key-value store, if key "FOO" doesn't already exist.

My annotation declaration is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface NodeProperty {
    long initialValue();  // I want to accept Strings, ints, byte[], etc. here.
}
```

But, I don't know the type of `initialValue` ahead of time.  I'd like to accept all primitives, Strings, and arrays of the these.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, it sounds like overloading the annotation parameter isn't currently possible.  The answers below contain various workarounds.

Comment: Compiler doesn't allow this because annotation parameter types must be  primitive, Class, String, Enum, or arrays of these.  Even the object versions of the primitives aren't allowed.

Comment: It's not a type issue, but a "constant at compile time" issue, I think.

Comment: It's still a type issue.  "Long.class" is constant-at-compile-time type but is not allowed. "long.class" is an allowed type.  Constant-at-compile-time might also be an intentional specification/requirement, but the type limitations exist as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept a single type (likely `String`) and use type conversion to get it from what-you-got to what-the-field-is. Similar to how Commons BeanUtils or XWork allow registering type converters to get from string form values to arbitrary Java classes.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the best workaround, I think.  It requires specifying two parameters in the annotation (the type and the string representation) --- far more annoying than just the actual value --- but it works!

Comment: @DavidB. It shouldn't, you have the type of the field--use it.

Comment: @Dave. As currently written, there isn't a field for the property, so your suggestion isn't possible. The only field is the key String. The type of the value is (or would ideally be) inferred from the initial value. The properties are stored in a third part object, so there is not field for each. Also, they aren't accessed outside of this class, so getters or setters that the annotation could be placed on instead aren't available or desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You could have different properties for different types, and then check to see which one has a value in your code.  So instead of initialValue, you might have initialInt, initialString, initial(...).  Cumbersome, but the only other way I can think of is to always use a String value and then parse the specific type from it.

Another option might be to reverse your declaration.  Have the key in the annotation, and the value as the variable being annotated?

Comment: Reversing the declaration is a clever idea.  Unfortunately I need the key accessible as as static final field, but otherwise that would work.

Comment: Another thought, although I'm not saying it is a great (or even good) idea, is to have the attribute property be the name of another field in the class which contains the default value and which you access via reflection.

Comment: This would certainly make the annotation processing code cleaner, at the expense of an extra static field.  Requiring that the default value be accessible as a static field wouldn't be too bad actually (at least as I envision things right now). These are all hacks around limitations of Java's annotation type system, but at least this one has some measurable positive side-effect (if you squint hard enough), not just negative ones.